# How to Load MS Word 2010 Add-in load after login and unload when exit

Tags: c#, add-in

I have windows application which enables user log-in. After Login I want the Add-in get loaded. and when user Exits that paticular Word instance(Only one instance of word can exists when the login application runs) then add-in is also unloaded. I have tried to do it by

```
 addin.Connect = false;//Application.COMAddins. Connect
```

It sets the LoadBehaviour( COM add-ins list) to 2
and when it loads i set it to 3

Its working but MSword displays so many error messages while exit and sometimes disables my add-in. 
Is there any other way to load and unload add-in dynamically?

Comment: I'm not clearly get life circle of your add-in, but I think would be best to have tiny add-in core. That core is loaded alway with word application and loads all your staff after user have been logged in

Comment: Actually my problem is how to load and unload add-in dynamically without any error message

Comment: All add-ins loaded during word application startup and it is solid. So I cant see any possible ways to achive your aim except described early one. Error messages you got likely occures because of errors in code. Try to debug your code, put `try` - `catch` blocks in you code to intercept exceptions, but be careful, interception is not a full solution. You should properly react to each catched  exception

Comment: I know word add-in get loaded automatically when word application starts up. but i want it to get loaded when user successfully logs-in. When User Logs in MS Word Application Opens With Add-in And my login application's work is complete. But i want When that instance of word closes then add-in also gets unloaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In add-in's StartUp event i checked the the property of login form. if it is set then execute following line

```
 addin.Connect = true;
```

and added a quit event handler

```
 ((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)app).Quit += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_QuitEventHandler(App_Quit);
```

in its App_Quit method

```
void App_Quit()
    {
       addin.Connect = false;
    }
```

Now when i quit word; my add-in is unloaded. finally it started working :-)